# Filetype for .log file when using HTML5 element input type="file"

Tags: html, file

I was playing around with using the `<input type="file" />` element and I have it accept a variety of different file types I wish to support.

```
<input type="file" name="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/jpg, application/pdf, application/txt, text/plain, application/pdf, text/x-log, application/enex+xml, text/*, .log" />
```

Depending on the file that is served, I can see what file type is passed by looking at the [FileList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList) which looks like this.

[image: FileList]

Everything works fine but for `.log`, as you can see above, doesn't have a `type`... I was wondering if there was a way to discern `.log` files? I could look at the `name` passed and parse the file extension, but was wondering if there was a better way? I'm also uncertain of what other file types do not have a registered `type` and if there is documentation on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't rely on the type returned. The available types will change depending on the browser and operating system. Generally it returns values registered with the os.

You can use the file name but that's not 100% reliable either. There's nothing preventing a user from renaming a zip file to .log. In most cases that will change the mime as well. The only way to be 100% sure is to read the file and see what it contains.

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks for the quick answer. I found the [FileAPI](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) by w3c in case people were curious but for the most part this answers my question.